# Unable to Run Apple's LoadPresetDemo The app paused and Xcode gives me me a SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, core-audio

I am making the scary leap of diving into CoreAudio. I have downloaded the apple Demo titled "LoadPresetDemo". I have made no modifications to the original code from apple. When I try to run it, it compiles without error, but the simulator freezes and it it says "Thread 1:singal SIGABRT". There are then 9 threads listed in the debug window. I have included the command line info below if that helps anyone figure out what is going on, but I should be able to run something written by apple without a problem. I have Digidesign Protools installed on this computer if that info is of any use. I am in over my head here and I have no Idea what to do next. Can anyone help me?

> 2012-05-07 18:30:21.453 Load Presets[852:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-05-07 18:30:21.510 Load Presets[852:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-05-07 18:30:21.549 Load Presets[852:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-05-07 18:30:21.558 Load Presets[852:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-05-07 18:30:21.575 Load Presets[852:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-05-07 18:30:21.583 Load Presets[852:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-05-07 18:30:21.601 Load Presets[852:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-05-07 18:30:21.609 Load Presets[852:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-05-07 18:30:21.698 Load Presets[852:10703] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-05-07 18:30:21.699 Load Presets[852:10703] Cannot find function pointer NewDigiCoreAudioPlugIn for factory B8A063B5-2F3D-444A-88CB-D0B8F1B22042 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x737e530  (bundle, not loaded)
>   2012-05-07 18:30:21.714 Load Presets[852:10703] *** Assertion failure in -[MainViewController configureAndStartAudioProcessingGraph:], /Users/micha liberman/Documents/Objective C Lessons/__Drop Droper Resources/LoadPresetDemo/LoadPresetDemo/Classes/MainViewController.m:170
>   2012-05-07 18:30:21.715 Load Presets[852:10703]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'AudioUnitSetProperty (set Sampler unit output stream sample rate). Error code: -10865 'è’ˇˇ''
>   ** First throw call stack:
>   (0x17a6022 0x28afcd6 0x174ea48 0xe312cb 0x3242 0x5293 0x21c9 0x498386 0x499274 0x4a8183 0x4a8c38 0x49c634 0x2e49ef5 0x177a195 0x16deff2 0x16dd8da 0x16dcd84 0x16dcc9b 0x498c65 0x49a626 0x20fc 0x20a5 0x1)
>   terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it exactly as you described.

In [your-app-name]-Info.plist (it is present under the first tab, "Show the Project Navigator") DELETE THE LINE "Main nib file base name (iPad)" with the content following until the end of line.

Cheers,
matrix3003